# Cast a non-terminal to java_cup.runtime.Symbol for empty case in grammar

Tags: java, runtime, symbols, cup

I am writing a compiler using JFlex and CUP. I am trying to parse the empty state in my .cup file. To simplify things, consider this grammar:

```
terminal    Integer            INT_LIT;
nonterminal List<Statement>    stmtlist;
nonterminal Statement          stmt;

start with stmtlist;

stmtlist    ::= stmtlist:sl stmt:s      {: sl.add(s); RESULT = sl; :}
            |                           {: RESULT = new LinkedList<Statement>(); :}
            ;

stmt        ::= INT_LIT:i               {: RESULT = Statement.stub(); :}
```

Here, Statement.stub() returns a stubbed Statement instance for testing purposes.

I get this error:

```
parser.java:653: error: incompatible types: List<Statement> cannot be converted to Symbol
          CUP$parser$result = parser.getSymbolFactory().newSymbol("stmtlist",2, ((java_cup.runtime.Symbol)CUP$parser$stack.peek()), RESULT);
```

I'm confused by this because the call to newSymbol provides the arguments:

```
parser.getSymbolFactory().newSymbol(String name, int id, Symbol left, Symbol right)
```

which is different than all of the other calls to newSymbol() in my parser. All other calls to newSymbol() are of the form:

```
parser.getSymbolFactory().newSymbol(String name, int id, Symbol left, Symbol right, Object value)
```

effectively casting RESULT to an Object instead of a Symbol.

So. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the empty case generating such a strange parser? And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by upgrading my Mac OS from 10.13 to 10.14, and installing CUP in /usr/bin. Unfortunately I'm not sure why this worked.